# How is it a closed question still receives answers?

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions

Take for example [this particular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559990/why-typename-is-required-even-though-it-seems-enough-to-deduce-the-name-should-b), although I have seen this occur a few times in the past as well.

It was closed as a duplicate (by myself), and yet there is an answer that appeared afterwards. And it's time-stamped about 8 minutes after the closure.

I **don't believe** there is any foul play on behalf of the answerer. I refreshed the page after closing and saw no FGITW deleted answer. The person who gave the answer clearly needed a while to type it, since it isn't bad at all.

How is this situation possible? Doesn't answering immediately become impossible when a question is closed?

Comment: obligatory shouldiblamecaching.com comment (though tbh, this doesn't make sense, as SO events are not subject to caching, but /we)

Comment: There is a grace period even after the question is closed. In that time, the check will only be performed at client end. If you're able to override it, you can post an answer

Comment: @SagarV - Yeah the duplicate (which I couldn't find myself) details that. I'd like to think people wouldn't try to abuse it, and this is simply a fair use of the grace period.